# Using generic ADTs

Tags: c++, generics, adt

I have a design problem. I'm asked to plan a design for a certain problem, where I need a few lists, and also a queue (which I need to create by myself, STL isn't allowed). In order to make the implementation more efficient, I thought about creating a generic list as follows: Create a node which contains a pointer to 'Data', an empty class. Then, any class that I want to make a list or a queue of (is the last sentence grammatically correct?), I'll just make it a subclass of data. That's the only way to make a generic list (I think), as we are not allowed to use void*.
The problem begins when I want to use a certain method of a certain class in a certain list. I can't do that, since 'Data' doesn't know that function. Creating a virtual function in Data is counter-logical and ugly, and we're also not allowed to use any downcasting.
Is there a way to overcome the problem using generic ADTs? Or must I create specific lists?
Thank you very much!
edit: We are also not allowed to use templates.

Comment: Templates are very much the canonical way to build generic data structures in C++, not subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

About the list and the queue, maybe you can adopt the same approach taken by the STL: just create the list, and then stack, as an adaptor of the list in which you only push and pop from the end.

About those contraints, which seems to be draconian, don't I suppose that the objective is for you to use templates?

Instead of creating and empty class, which if does not contain any method does not serve you at all, use a template as in the following example:

```
template<typename T>
class List {

    class Node {
    public:
        Node(T* d)
            { data.reset( new Data( d ) ); }
        T * getData()
            { return data; }
        Node * getSig()
            { return sig; }
    private:
        std::auto_ptr<T> data;
        Node * sig;
    };

    List()...
// Lots of more things...
};
```

You can find more info here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beware of the auto_ptr in this case. Are you sure this will behave correctly when the default copy constructor and assignment operator will be involved. Also, what's the point to re-implement the standard library?

Comment: Oh, we're also not allowed to use templates. Draconian indeed. But maybe it's for a reason. Taken from the exercise's FAQ: "Q: Can I use Template?
A: No, and I will explain you in the code review meeting why, even if was allowed, it would not have been the right tool for the design." Is there any other way?

Comment: @Alessandro, you should carefully check the question from the op. Then you'll be able to answer your question by yourself.

Comment: @user1330810, if there is another way I don't know about it. Generic programming (templates) and polymorphism (inheritance + virtual methods) are the only way to create collections that do not depend on a given, specific class.

Comment: @Baltasarq That's my point, if they are not allowed to use the standard library I was assuming that the template were not suitable as well.

Comment: I guess that I need to create specific lists then. Thanks.